# R function to create reactive column names

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

So I have created a bigger function that loads in the data I need and cleanses it etc.

Currently inside of my function I have a list of names.

I also have a tibble with all my datasets there.

I want to create a column "source" in each of my datasets that will be populated with appropriate name, so then when I combine all datasets into one, I can still know which month each rows comes from.

I tried many different things, but it either gave me an error message about atomic vector, or didn't like the fact that I was trying $ notation for columns.

The snippet below nearly does what it needs to, however it overwrites last name in all datasets, whereas I would like to take first name and create source_month in first dataframe with value for each rows equal to that month and so on.

Regards

```
  for (name in dataframe_names){
    for (dataframe in data){
      lapply(data,mutate,source_month = name)
      }
```